# Tizen Selector touch event

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I want to open different pages from a popup-selector menu in Tizen.
I have 8 menu items and each should open a different page in the same HTML using the active-ui-page class.
I tried doing it using the code mentioned [here](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/wearable/circular_support/components/moreoptions.htm).

But then when I transfer back to the selector, them indicator-name doesn't change.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to make sure you are not closing the popup or destroying the [Selector](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/wearable/widgets/widget_selector.htm). In such way your selector is may be getting nonfunctional. **tau.closePopup()** will close the popUp window, thus selector won't appear back.

```
elSelector.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
        if (target.classList.contains("ui-selector-indicator")) {
            tau.closePopup(popupCircle);  //**comment out this line**//
            //your code 
        }
    }
});
```

**selector.destroy()** destroys & removes event listener, which might be the case in your situation, that's why indicator-name isn't changing.

```
selector.destroy();  //**comment out this line**//
```

Vice versa for solution try calling the popUp window again using **tau.openPopup()** :

```
if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
    tau.openPopup(popupCircle);
}
```

otherwise call the selector again with **tau.widget.Selector()**

```
if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
    var radius = window.innerHeight / 2 * 0.8;
    selector = tau.widget.Selector(elSelector, {itemRadius: radius});
}
```

Code souce : ['TAUUIComponents'  (Tizen Sample Web app)](https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/web/UI/TAU_UI_Components_1)

Thank you.

Comment: @user1039985... if you think the answer is helpful for you, then you should select it as "Best Answer" which will promote this answer to others.